# How do I display the Kubernetes Pod Name in a Vue.js app

Tags: nginx, vue.js, kubernetes

I have a vue.js frontend connecting to an Express node.js backend. Both frontend and backend are running in separate Docker containers on Kubernetes. I have created a route on the backend to display the Kubernetes Pod name when I call the URL via Postman:

```
app.get('/api/probe1', (req, res) => {
    res.send("Hello from: " + process.env.HOSTNAME)
})
```

The above shows the name of the Pod on which the BACKEND container is running.

I now want to create a page in my vue.js app which will display the name of the Pod on which the FRONTEND container is running **edit: (as per comment below vue.js not really *running* on the pod but rather nginx serving static html/js is running on the pod).**

When I use process.env.HOSTNAME in the vue.js app I get "undefined" when I console.log it. **edit: (I can now see why this isn't going to work)**

```
<template>
<div>{{displayPodName}}
  <p>Hello from the Pod</p>
</div>
</template>
<script>
export default {  
        data(){
            return{
                displayPodName:""
        }
    },
    mounted(){
        this.displayPodName=process.env.HOSTNAME
        console.log(process.env.HOSTNAME)
     }
}
</script>
```

I'm clearly tackling this from the wrong angle. How can I display the name of the Pod **edit: <strike>on which the Frontend is running in my Vue.js app somewhere</strike> from which a particular nginx server is serving the html/js to my browser for any given session please?**

Comment: You're kinda barking up the wrong tree. Remember - Vue isn't _running_ in the Pod; it's just being _served_ from there. It's running in your browser.

Comment: That helps thanks @SebastianLenartowicz so what's running in that FE pod is really nginx hosting a bunch of static html and js right? How would you then tackle to task of displaying the pod name from which the nginx server is serving the html/js? Said differently... I want to see the name of the FE pod involved in making the web page show in my browser for any particular session. I'll update my question above.

Comment: That's correct. Though I really have to ask _why_ you're doing this. K8s isn't meant to be used that way - if you scale up the Deployment running the frontend or backend Pods, you'll get a different value every time you make the request. Half the point of the Pod abstraction is that Pods are meant to be fungible - any one Pod is exactly the same as any other.

Comment: Good question. Was more of a theoretical challenge I wanted to be able to solve as part of my vue and k8s journey but you’ve convinced me its pointless and not necessary. Thanks.