# Is it good practice or necessary to protect an API with authentication even if the data is not sensitive?

Tags: vue.js, google-authentication

My Vue.js app which interacts with data via a Node.js backend accesses both sensitive and non-sensitive data. I have been able to protect the API's on the Node server, the ones working with **sensitive** data (such as updating pricing information) using the [google authentication API](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/authentication). This requires a user to have to login with a google account before being able to interact with those API's.

I'm now trying to protect the API's which simply retrieve **non-sensitive** data (such as Names, descriptions, prices of products I sell, etc.) so that even said API's cannot be accessed directly without some form of authentication. ie. If I used something like Postman to retrieve data from the API directly, without authenticating I would not be able to get any data. However, these API's are accessed from a part of the Vue.app which does not require login. ie. Users on the site may see Product, pricing etc. information without having to login first.

In order to protect these "non-sensitive" API's I would have to pass some "secret" such as an API Key from the Vue front-end to the Node backend. I believe from 2 other posts I've done ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53010064/pass-environment-variable-into-a-vue-app-at-runtime) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53083980/how-do-i-display-the-kubernetes-pod-name-in-a-vue-js-app)) that it isn't possible to pass Environmental variables into a Vue App at run-time (I'm using Vue CLI 3). This leaves me with having to hardcode the API Key into the front-end code which means it is no longer "secret" or secure.

I'm in essence trying to do "Application Authentication" but without the ability to pass ENV Variables in Vue at run-time I don't know how to do this securely.

Everything I read on the internet points to either:

1. Passing ENV Variables into Vue at build-time (which isn't secure in this scenario); or
2. That I'm missing something for wanting to pass ENV Variables into Vue at run-time in the first place.

Question: Am I overthinking or overcomplicating things by trying to protect data which isn't sensitive?

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing so is the following:

1. Upon successful authentication generate a [JSON Web Token](https://jwt.io/)
2. Send token back to the client (Vue app) and store it in the browser's local storage
3. On the API route you want to secure add a function that will check whether the the request contains the token you provided on Step 2. You can send the token as part of the request body or maybe a header.

This is a simple yet effective way of securing an API.